# Can 2 separate macbook Pros work on one imovie project at the same time?

Tags: video, imovie

I have a question regarding Imovie. I am wondering if 2 separate MacBooks can work on the same iMovie project at the same time. I am working on a project with a partner. When I say "at the same time", I mean that both computers can move scenes around, and add commentary and music at the same time. The same project can be open on two separate computers and an edit on one computer shows up on the other. Basically, I am asking if iMovie can work just like Google Docs, 2 people can make edits in real time at the same time. If so, how can I connect the two MacBooks together on the same project?
If this doesn't work on iMovie, will it work on final cut pro? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Collaborate with Others” function()   I think it is on right top corner of app. ;)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info on how to do what you're suggesting. Also, you may want to read [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.

Comment: It is pretty self explanatory//